# How to config email alert in using grafana and prometheus-operator

Tags: grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I installed prometheus-operator (include prometheus/alertmanager/grafana) via helm. Then I access Grafana UI and config alert via email. When I click send an email test, I got the message “ SMTP not configured, check your grafana.ini config file’s [smtp] section”

[image]

**But I don’t know where the grafana.ini to can change in this case.**

```
[root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-5bbc8f45cb-nlqgh                  1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   calico-node-lk2j5                                         1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   calico-node-v6wzs                                         1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   calico-node-zfh5r                                         1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-79c2g                                  1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-bqj7g                                  1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master                                           1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master                                 1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master                        1/1     Running   2          15h
kube-system   kube-proxy-8qmdt                                          1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   kube-proxy-qwgbc                                          1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   kube-proxy-vhqjd                                          1/1     Running   1          15h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master                                 1/1     Running   1          15h
monitoring    alertmanager-prometheus-operator-alertmanager-0           2/2     Running   3          15h
monitoring    prometheus-operator-grafana-64848fc9bb-dbnwc              2/2     Running   3          15h
monitoring    prometheus-operator-kube-state-metrics-5d46566c59-ck4np   1/1     Running   2          15h
monitoring    prometheus-operator-operator-64dcc7bfc-lpdj6              2/2     Running   2          15h
monitoring    prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-ns4kg        1/1     Running   1          15h
monitoring    prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-tdhwq        1/1     Running   2          15h
monitoring    prometheus-operator-prometheus-node-exporter-xt8z9        1/1     Running   2          15h
monitoring    prometheus-prometheus-operator-prometheus-0               3/3     Running   4          15h
```

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to override this configuration, using helm variables, thanks to [alertmanager.config](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator/#alertmanager) key.
This key convert yaml into configuration for alertmanager, so you can use every [alertmanager configuration](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#configuration-file).
You should probably also change [grafana.ini](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator/#grafana) configuration to [configure smtp](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/#smtp) into grafana (test seems to use that configuration). You can check this configuration in Grafana via "Server admin" > "Settings", search "smtp".

As a reference, you can do something like the following for alertmanager :

```
    helm upgrade --install prometheus stable/prometheus-operator \
-f helm/prometheus-operator.yml \
-f helm/grafana-custom.staging.yml \
--set-string alertmanager.config.global.smtp_smarthost="my.smtp.tld:465" \
--set-string alertmanager.config.global.smtp_auth_username="my@email.tld" \
--set-string alertmanager.config.global.smtp_from="my@email.tld" \
--set-string alertmanager.config.global.smtp_auth_password="MyAmazingPassword" \
--set-string grafana.'grafana\.ini'.smtp.enabled=true \
--set-string grafana.'grafana\.ini'.smtp.host="my.smtp.tld:465" \
--set-string grafana.'grafana\.ini'.smtp.from_address="my@email.tld" \
--set-string grafana.'grafana\.ini'.smtp.user="my@email.tld" \
--set-string grafana.'grafana\.ini'.smtp.password="MyAmazingPassword"
```

Answer (score 4):

The grafana.ini is loaded through configmaps in prometheus-operator helm deployment. If you have already installed it via helm then you can just modify the configmap and then restart the grafana pod. Below is minimum config with which i was able to use SMTP.

```
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = your.smtp.server.name:25
skip_verify = true
from_address = "grafana@xyz.com"
from_name = Grafana
```

To get the configmap, run below command and edit the configmap(include namespace in below command if prometheus-operator is deployed in a speratae name space than default).

```
kubectl get configmap | grep grafana
```

After editing configmap, restart grafana pod(restarts of other pods is no needed).

Note: Skip_verify = true is not recommended.